# Getting HEAD content with Python Requests

Tags: python, head, http-request, python-requests

I'm trying to parse the result of a HEAD request done using the Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/index.html) library, but can't seem to access the response content.

According to the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/), I should be able to access the content from requests.Response.text. This works fine for me on GET requests, but returns None on HEAD requests.

**GET request (works)**

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.text
```

content = `<html>...</html>`

**HEAD request (no content)**

```
import requests
response = requests.head(url)
content = response.text
```

content = `None`

---

**EDIT**

OK I've quickly realized form the answers that the HEAD request is not supposed to return content- only headers. But does that mean that, to access things found IN the `<head>` tag of a page, like `<link>` and `<meta>` tags, that one must GET the whole document?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By [definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4), the responses to HEAD requests do not contain a message-body.

Send a GET request if you want to, well, get a response body. Send a HEAD request [iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff) you are only interested in the response status code and headers.

HTTP transfers arbitrary content; the HTTP term *header* is completely unrelated to an HTML `<head>`. However, HTTP can be advised to download only a part of the document. If you know the length of the HTML `<head>` code (or an upper boundary therefor), you can include an [HTTP Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header in your request that advises the remote server to only return a certain number of bytes. If the remote server supports HTTP ranges, it will then serve the reduced answer.

Comment: OK my mistake- but then how does one capture things like `<link>` and `meta` tags from a HEAD request- or is that not possible?

Comment: Umm, `<link>` and `<meta>` tags are only present in the HTML **body**.  The only headers you can access are the HTTP ones. *Why* do you want to send a HEAD instead of a GET anyways?

Comment: phihag- ? `<meta>` tags are within the `<head>` section of a doc- view source on this page. I was hoping to get only the `<head>` to reduce time on link scraping.

Comment: You're confusing similar terms in the context of different protocols. HTTP does not know anything about HTML code; it just transfers arbitrary content with headers (for example for the content type or its expiration date). If you know the length of the HTML `<head>`, you can include the [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header in your request, but I'll doubt that will speed up things unless the full HTML code is really huge.

Answer (score 10):

A HEAD doesn't have any content! Try `response.headers` - that's probably where the action is. An HTTP HEAD request doesn't get the `<head>` element of the HTML response you would get from a GET request. I think that's your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

HEAD responses have no body. They only return HTTP headers, the same you would get using a GET request.