# Python, Requests Session, HTML head not showing

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am playing with the requests module in python and I am stuck with a problem.

I use requests to login on a website (http://coinplants.com) using the Session class. After the login I am trying to read the html of the page and I realized that the response object shows only the html body with it's content but not the html head. I would like to get the html head with the meta tags. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('http://coinplants.com', data=postData)
print r.text
```

Thanks in advance :)

**LOGIN**

To scrap the authenticity token I use BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
finding = soup.find('input', {'name' : 'authenticity_token'})
postData = {'utf8' : '%E2%9C%93', 'authenticity_token' : '',
        'account[email]' : self.username, 'account[password]' : self.password,
         'account[remember_me]' : '0', 'commit' : 'Log+in'}
postData['authenticity_token'] = finding['value']
r = s.post('http://coinplants.com/accounts/sign_in', data=postData)
```

**Solution**

Ok, I found a solution to my problem. I have no idea why the session doesn't give me the whole html content. I took the cookie from the session object and added it to a request object:

```
cookies = {'_faucet:session' : s.cookies['_faucet_session']}
r = requests.get('http://coinplants.com', cookies=cookies)
print r.text
```

s is the session object. When I print the text of the response object it shows me the whole html content, including head tag. If someone knows why the session object is not showing it, please let me know :)

Comment: Are you sure your login is successful?

Comment: Yes it is successful. I checked the html after the login.

Comment: Can you add the post data obviously minus your email/passsword? I see a csrf token is required so unless you are scraping that I don't see how your login is successful

Comment: I added the login to the my question.

Comment: Looks ok, do you definitely see the head tags in your browser when you choose view source?

Comment: Yes, I can see it and that's what confuses me.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, try adding a user-agent. Also when you monitor the request in chrome tools, check the response tab for the post and make sure you see the data there.

Comment: I added a user-agent but still no html head content. I tried now chrome and the chrome tools and the response has the head tag. Same for FF...

Answer (score 0):

When i understand you right you are looking for the headers of the page.

when you type

`print r.headers`

you should get the headers of the page.

Or did i understand your question wrong?

This page is very helpfull to learn more about the request module. 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: The

r.headers

returns the HTTP headers, which the server sends to me and not the HTML head tag. I guess you understood it wrong. But I will have a look on the link and hope to find there something.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. but i hope the link can help you! :-)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554947/getting-head-content-with-python-requests) take a look to this question.

Comment: I just had a look on it. I read a bit about the Range header in HTTP and I tried to use it, but somehow I get the whole html body content, even I ask for 100 bytes...

Answer (score -1):

Print out the req.url which is getting and then try to scrap that url using get.

```
url = r.url
req = s.get(url)
print req.text
```

See is it resolving your issue or not. If not then go to the r.url in browser and inspect the element using whatever browser you are comfortable and see whether the head tag is showing or not. I hope it helped.

Comment: This is not helping.

    url = r.url returns http://coinplants.com 

This is the url I am sending the GET request. Using FF I am having a look on the html and I see there a html head and html body tag and both with content. As soon I use requests I don't get the html head tag :(