# Getting empty response using request with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, request, web-crawler

I am trying to make requests bases on a list of url, then check the content of the response for each.
I found this snipped on SO which seemed to work well, if I output the response of the request I get the corect result, but as soon as I want to return the content it is empty... why?

```
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import time

out = []
CONNECTIONS = 100
TIMEOUT = 5

tlds = open('rez.txt').read().splitlines()
urls = ['http://{}'.format(x) for x in tlds[1:]]

def load_url(url, timeout):
    ans = requests.head(url, timeout=timeout)
    return ans

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
    future_to_url = (executor.submit(load_url, url, TIMEOUT) for url in urls)
    time1 = time.time()
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):

        try:
            data = future.result()
            #why is data.content empty??
            print(data.content)
        except Exception as exc:
            data = str(type(exc))
        finally:
            out.append(data)
            #print(out)
            print(str(len(out)),end="\r")

    time2 = time.time()

print(f'Took {time2-time1:.2f} s')
print(pd.Series(out).value_counts())
```

Output of this code:

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

Original thread:
[Getting HEAD content with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554947/getting-head-content-with-python-requests)

Comment: I'm confused by this line _if I output the response of the request I get the corect result, but as soon as I want to return the content it is empty_ - what do you mean by response?

Comment: I mean data.status_code would return status code like 200,301...

But if I use data.content it outputs what is above

Comment: By definition, responses to HEAD requests have no body (content), only headers.  What information are you trying to retrieve?