# How do I make a HTTP HEAD request using requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-head

How do I make a [HTTP HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request using the requests library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting HEAD content with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554947/getting-head-content-with-python-requests)

Comment: @buran No, it's not because I don't want to get the content, I only want the header data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [`head()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.head) function:

```
r = requests.head(INSERT_URL_HERE)
```