# Is there a faster way to check the availability of numerous websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, python-requests

Good day, everyone.

This code is checking availability if the website, but it's loading the whole page, so if I have a list of **100 websites**, it will be slow.

My Question is: Is there any way to do it faster?

```
import requests
user_agent = {'accept': '*/*', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("http://google.com", headers=user_agent, timeout=5)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Checked & avaliable")
else:
    print("Not avaliable")
```

Thanks!

Every Help Will Be Appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a website is up via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949318/checking-if-a-website-is-up-via-python)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use That:

```
import urllib.request
print(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com").getcode())
#output
>>> 200
```

Comment: Thanks! For me this way is 20% faster

Comment: @EgorVasko If My Answer Helpful To You Can You Please Accept My answer! by clicking check icon

Answer (score 1):

> This code is checking availability if the website, but it's loading the whole page

To not load the whole page, you can issue `HEAD` requests, instead of `GET`, so you will just check the status. See [Getting HEAD content with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554947/getting-head-content-with-python-requests)

Another way to make it faster, is to issue multiple requests using multiple threads or asyncio ( https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html ).

Comment: Authorization headers will be removed if you get redirected off-host: google.com will be redirected and as a result - Not avaliable